# Source code of linux init process

Tags: linux

I want to figure out what is exactly going on in init process (/sbin/init) of Linux, but it is quite hard to find one.
Could you tell me who maintains the source code of init process?

Comment: What have you searched for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on Linux version. Traditionally, [`sysvinit`](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/sysvinit/) was used.

These days, many Linux distros use [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/download.html).

Some others, like Fedora, are using [`systemd`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd).

Comment: is upstart compiled and the binary is saved as "init"? Becuase, in my Linux, I still see init process from ps aux

Comment: Yes, all `init` alternatives provide own `init` binary together with some common tools, like `telinit`, `initctl`, etc. Also, they provide custom enhancements like `start`/`stop` for upstart, or `systemctl` for `systemd`.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the source code of the `sysvinit` package [here](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot/SysVinit-6314.shtml).

Note that some Linux distributions do not use System V Init anymore. For instance, Debian, Fedora and Ubuntu use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks. This is the one that I'm looking for :) And about upstart, I'm using ubuntu and I see init in ps aux. I think init is still used for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

There are several variants of init. Many Linux distributions use systemd while Ubuntu for example uses upstart. The source code can be downloaded from the project web site or using the system's package manager.